# How to avoid an expand and collapse that I get from a DFP Div?

Tags: html, css, google-dfp

I´m using DFP to deliver some direct sale ads for [a site](https://www.okchicas.com/).

I want to have a 2.5rem space in between the content and my menu bar.

1. If [an ad is displayed](https://www.okchicas.com/?google_preview=pQLL4gSdXasYuMKnxQUwuN7czAWIAYCAgKCLt4iP4gE&iu=86430479&gdfp_req=1&lineItemId=258511639&creativeId=124392743839) it will show it obv. (And ill have 2.5rem above and below the ad, so it looks nice for the visitor
2. If there´s no ad as it is right now, the divs will collapse but theres a problem in this:

   - When the page loads the padding rule that .topbillboard has (`.topbillboard {margin:2.5rem 0!important;}`  will expand the content temporaly (Just matter of milliseconds in the load) a 5rem space then it will collapse back to 2.5rem:
   - This is really annoying since I dont want this content push and then collapse. I just want since the initial load to show just the 2.5rem space (If theres an ad or not)
   - But If I dont use this padding, when the ad is delivered it will have [no space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7gGW.jpg) in between the ad and my `.content-sidebar-wrap`.

Is there any way to be able to not move this spaces??? This is driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

it's because DFP needs some time to load, best workaround is to set some min-`height` to `.topbillboard` so that it will not be "flashy" on load